# Draw Another Border in line on Canvas

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, border, stroke

I have problem. I need draw another border in my canvas. If I try this:

```
c2.beginPath();

c2.moveTo(0, 0);

c2.lineTo(0, 100);
c2.lineWidth = Number(sw) + 6;
c2.strokeStyle = "red";
c2.stroke();
c2.lineTo(100, 100);
c2.lineWidth = Number(sw) + 6;
c2.strokeStyle = "#00ec11";
c2.stroke();
c2.lineTo(0, 100);
c2.lineWidth = Number(ss) + 6;
c2.strokeStyle = "red";
c2.stroke();
c2.closePath();
c2.lineWidth = Number(sw) + 6;
c2.strokeStyle = "#00ec11";
c2.stroke();

c2.fill();
```

it is not working because all line have green border. Can you help me?

--- Edit:
I can;t close patch when close my line bacouse this line draw shape. When i close patch my shape isn't correct. Mayby another ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`c2.stroke();` redraws the whole path up to that point with the current strokeStyle. So in the end, only the last style will be applied.

Try adding `c2.closePath();` followed by `c2.beginPath()` after each `c2.stroke()` to begin a new path which can have a separate strokeStyle.

for example:

```
c2.lineTo(0, 100);
c2.lineWidth = Number(sw) + 6;
c2.strokeStyle = "red";
c2.stroke();
c2.closePath();

c2.beginPath();
c2.moveTo(0, 100);
c2.lineTo(100, 100);
c2.lineWidth = Number(sw) + 6;
c2.strokeStyle = "#00ec11";
c2.stroke();
c2.closePath();
. 
. 
.
```